# Deep link not working for a case

Tags: swift

Hey I am developing an app for the version iOS7 and above, where I have to share a content via mail or message. I use the following code

```
let textToShare = "Just click the following link to view "
let urlToShare = NSURL(string: "croding.com://crodid/crodname")
let objectsToShare = [textToShare, urlToShare]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have added the croding.com in plist. Its working fine (open our app from mail exactly what I want) only if the app is installed already otherwise this thing is just a text instead of link. I need to show it as link even app is not installed.

> croding.com://crodid/crodname

Comment: What is your question?  What problem are you having that you need help with?

Comment: even if you succeed in showing that as link it will show the error as the app is not installed